# Windows Installer Folder Exists Property

Tags: windows-installer, setup-project, file-exists

I am creating a Windows Setup Project for a Windows Forms application. Typically our application gets deployed to two different clients, those with a specific Printer Driver, and those without. Our current installshield setup checks to see if the drivers exist based on whether or not a directory exists (i.e. C:\PrinterDriver). If the directory exists, the setup copies over the necessary files.

In the WindowsInstaller project's File System, I created the folder C:\MyProjectFiles\PrinterDriver. I want those files to be copied only if the directory C:\PrinterDriver exists. If the directory does NOT exist, the setup should still proceed without copying over the files, but not rollback. Any ideas on how to approach this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a [file search](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0x2fc4kd) and use the property in the file [condition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ddtk4a95.aspx#vxconfileinstallationpropertiesanchor3).

Comment: VS deployment project is very limited. I guess you must enter a file name for the build to pass. Your other options is write a custom action or move to [WiX](http://wixtoolset.org).

Comment: If I stick to doing it with Windows installer, my only option would then be to create a new C++ Custom Action. Or can custom actions be done in C#?

Comment: [Custom action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d9k65z2d.aspx) can be in written in C# with a the obvious limitation the target machine must have .NET framework. Or you can simply point to a known file name under `C:\PrinterDriver`

Comment: But it runs after files are already copied not before :( That's what I already have in my project.

Comment: Launch conditions runs before the installation begins, so you should be able to discover if a file exists or not.